# Multiple WiFi Router

Tags: router, internet, connection, switch, isp

I have 9 WiFi routers connected to switch, 2 of the routers cannot connect to the internet unless I shutdown 2 router.

Should I use static configuration to all routers ?

-9 WiFi routers connected to 1 switch and switch connected to modem isp
-DHCP

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which model of switch? How are the routers connected?

Comment: Welcome to SU. As presented your question is impossible to answer. You need to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775740/edit) the question to provide a lot more information; for example what @harrymc is asking. "How connected" means which port connects where. "Should I use static configuration" - what configuration, WAN, LAN, DHCP...? It'd be a good idea also to explain what exactly is the goal you want to achieve by having 9 routers. In general the devil's in the details - the more you give, the better answers you can have. Please don't provide new info in comments, but edit the question.

Comment: Oh yeah... which routers exactly? Are they running in router mode or AP mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `2 of the routers cannot connect to the internet unless I shutdown 2 router.` is it a random 2 that can't connect, and another random 2 that you shutdown?